# how to load kmz files in a KML Region from FTP server

Tags: ftp, kml, region

I had a problems to integrate kmz files from an FTP-server in into a kml region.

```html
             <NetworkLink>
                  <name>TAsi_0005_1_1_2</name>
                  <TimeSpan>
                      <begin>2011-07-01T00:00:00Z</begin>
                      <end>2011-07-04T23:59:59Z</end>
                  </TimeSpan>
                  <Region>
                      <LatLonAltBox>
                          <north>10.0</north>
                          <south>5.0025</south>
                          <east>70.0</east>
                          <west>65.0</west>
                      </LatLonAltBox>
                      <Lod>
                          <minLodPixels>512</minLodPixels>
                          <maxLodPixels>-1 </maxLodPixels>
                      </Lod>
                  </Region>
                  <Link>
                     <a href = "ftp://ftp.servername/KMLs">
               </a>
                  </Link>
              </NetworkLink>
```

Maybe I forgot something or even it is not practicable ?

I'm using a public FTP server

Answer (score 0):

Your `<Link>` tag should contain an `<href>` tag, NOT an `<a href=...>` tag (that's an HTML thing).

So your example should look something like this:

```
<NetworkLink>
  ...
  <Link>
    <href>ftp://ftp.servername/KMLs</href>
  </Link>
</NetworkLink>
```